# Do individual photons increase entropy as they travel?

Tags: photons, entropy

If I draw a control volume around a single light wave traveling through empty space, is entropy increasing as it goes?  How is the degradation of the quality of energy manifested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, light propagating through space doesn't increase entropy. It's generally considered to be a reversible process, for the simple reason that a suitably curved mirror can be used to restore the initial state. Instead, entropy is produced when light is absorbed or emitted from any surface or volume.

In the ideal case of a black body, the entropy produced by emission is $\frac{4}{3}\frac{J}{T}$, where $T$ is the temperature of the body and $J$ is the net rate of emission, in $\mathrm{Js^{-1}}$. This entropy is associated with the light radiating away from the black body, and its entropy doesn't change until it is absorbed by another body.

Comment: Doesn't light lose energy when it travels long distances through space?  I was wondering about how the loss of energy happens. It feels strange that light can just keep going forever (like perpetual motion).

Comment: Perpetual motion in itself is nothing strange. In vacuum, were there's no friction, any object in motion will remain in (uniform) motion. Similarly, light will always travel if it's not absorbed, w/o loosing energy. It however usually looses intensity, as the light beam broadens.

Answer (score 1):

Entropy is a statistical quantity. There is little meaning to the entropy of a single photon, just as there is little meaning to the entropy of a single gas molecule. One could argue that if the state of the photon is known, its entropy is 0 and therefore so is the change of entropy which at least doesn't violate $\Delta S\ge 0$. However, the second law really only holds for statistical ensembles.

Comment: So if I modify my question to be regarding 1000000 photons all traveling together, does that change your answer?

Comment: If you know the state of all of those 1000000 photons exactly, no. But that's the point of entropy, you don't. Entropy is a measure for the *lack of information*. In that sense it is an entirely subjective quantity.

Comment: When we talk about "the" entropy, we mean the entropy w.r.t. the canonical ensemble, i.e. we know only the temperature and that the system is at thermal equilibrium but we do not know the exact state of every single particle.

Comment: Even with only one photon, the entropy need not be zero -- if you don't know the state exactly. But if you do, and you'd have to in order to put a "control volume" around it at all times, there is just no information lacking.

Comment: If you'd like to know more about the microscopic foundation of entropy, I refer you to the excellent book by Roger Balian, *From microphysics to macrophysics*, specifically chapter 3.